# MailChimp PATCH request

Tags: swift, mailchimp

I have been on this for a week now but keep getting a 401 error. Any advice would be great.

I'm trying to update a html template in the Mailchimp campaign.

```
 func MailChimp() {
      
        var params: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:]
        params["name"] = TemplateName
        params["html"] = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>   <head>  <img src=\"\(imageURL)\" width=\"320\" height=\"568\"></head></html>"
        let postData = encodeRequestParams(params)
        
        let authenticationString = "anystring: \(mailChimpAPI)"
        let authenticationData = authenticationString.data(using: .ascii)
        let authenticationValue = authenticationData?.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        
        let url = "https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/templates/\(TemplateID)"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "\(url)")! as URL)
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
 
        request.httpMethod = "PATCH"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.setValue("Basic \(authenticationValue!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        request.httpBody = postData

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("This is the URL.... \(url)")
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response))")
            
        })
        task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Try `request.addValue("Basic \(authenticationValue!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")` since you have not added the Authorization to request you can not set it.

Comment: Not related, but prefer Stuff over NSStuff when available, it would also avoid using recast/bridge: `NSMutableURLRequest` => `URLRequest`, `NSURL` => `URL`..

Comment: @Larme Good catch.  Myke - one other thing you can use Postman to test stuff like this and then it has an option to export it to code Swift URLSession.

Comment: Remove the space in `"anystring: \(mailChimpAPI)"`